# InteliJ: Spring Boot and Angular Live Reload

Tags: angular, spring-boot, ide

I have a spring boot maven project and an Angular 5 project. I typically buid the "dist" folder npm run build:prod then add it to src/main/resources/public and then boot the spring project.

How can I include the source for the Angular project inside the spring boot project so that when the spring boot app is running I can make live edits to the html and typescript files?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to setup also hot reloading for your Spring Boot Project. Take a look on this as start point: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html

Comment: This works for static resource like using Angular JS, but for Angular2+ you have Typescript files that are edited and the LiveReload/Edit does not work.